# C++ DLL fails to load on some machines

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm trying to figure out the reason why my DLL fails to load on certain machines.

**My application:**

A C# program deployed with a setup.msi installer. Inside the installer are the DLLs that get placed in the install directory of the application. Ex:

```
OUTDIR = c:\Program Files\MyApplicationName\%OUTDIR%\MyApplication.exe
dir %OUTDIR%\DLL_FOLDER\\*.dll
```

**myDLL.dll**

The C# application calls LoadLibrary specified by:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libname);
```

So basically

```
intPtr dll_handle = LoadLibrary("myDll.dll");
```

Is called and we use the dll_handle to call the desired functions.

So far this has worked on 5/7 of the machines I've deployed it on... What are the obvious mistakes I'm making here? :-)

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Usually this is a DLL dependency problem. Check with the dependency walker whether the DLL has everything it depends on available.

Comment: Is the `DLL_FOLDER` in the search path for DLLs somehow? If not, why can't you just put the DLL into the `%OUTDIR%` itself?

Comment: @PeterT : Yes Peter I could just aswell place it in the same folder.     DLL_FOLDER was used to "keep things neat".

Comment: Use Dependency Walker:  [http://www.dependencywalker.com](http://www.dependencywalker.com)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most likely explanations are:

1. The DLL cannot be found. Since you don't specify a full path, you rely on the [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) to locate it. Placing the DLL in the same directory as the executable is the usual way to make sure you can find it, and find the right version.
2. The DLL has non-matching bitness. For instance, your have a 64 bit process and a 32 bit DLL, or vice versa.
3. The DLL is found, and has the right bitness, but the DLL's dependencies cannot be resolved. Usually this means that the appropriate MSVC runtime needs to be installed on the target machine.

The first diagnostics step to take is to check the return value of `LoadLibrary` and if it is `NULL` then call `GetLastError` to retrieve an error code. In p/invoke you do that like so:

```
IntPtr lib = LoadLibrary(...);
if (lib == IntPtr.Zero)
    throw new Win32Exception();
```

You can use a tool like Dependency Walker to debug the problem further.

Comment: Hefferman, Thanks for yor detailed answer! I'm quite confident on points 1 & 2 while i suspect it might be something regarding the MSVC runtime like you suggested. Using the dependency walker I found that the sometimes failing DLL is depedant on MSVCP100.DLL,MSVCR100.DLL, VCOMP100.DLL, and kenerl32.dll. I suspect the first 3 are related to the VS runtime?

Comment: Oh also, If I run the dependency walker on one of my failing machines, will it be able to tell me which dependency is missing on that particular machiens?

Comment: Indeed VCOMP100.dll is missing on the target machine according to dependencywalker, what is the best course of action? Install VS2010 runtime on each deployment machine?

Comment: VCOMP100? Is that OpenMP? I guess you need to work out what it is and read thge redist docs.

Comment: indeed it is... still working on the deployment cause adding: Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x64.msm and Microsoft_VC100_MFC_x64.msm modules  to the setup project did not seem to solve the issue...